# Commit utilizando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Definindo **SET AUTOCOMMIT=0** na conexão, mas não está funcionando.

Estou utilizando **$mysqli->real_connect()**

```
if (!$conn->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT=0')) {
    $fErro .= '<p>Não foi possível desativar o autocommit</p>';
}
```

Versão do PHP 5.4.9 ou 5.6.12.
Estou tendo o mesmo problema.

Comment: Não da erro na linha do AUTOCOMMIT=0

Comment: Pergunta, o usuário logado para fazer esse comando tem os privilégios necessários ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Welguri**, o ideal seria utilizar `transaction` que implicitamente desabilita o autocommit até que seja comitado e é super simples e seguro:

```
<?php
    try 
    {
        // Primeiro de tudo, vamos começar a transação
        $conn->beginTransaction();

        // Um conjunto de querys, se uma falhar, um exception será lançado
        $conn->query('primeira query');
        $conn->query('segunda query');
        $conn->query('terceira query');

        // Se nós chegamos até aqui, significa que nenhum exception (erro) foi lançado
        // então nós comitamos a transação
        $conn->commit();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        // Uma exception foi lançada
        // Nós então precisamos voltar as alterações
        $conn->rollback();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.commit.php), para desativar o `autocommit`:

```
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Bavarian', 'F', 11.2)");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Swabian', 'F', 9.4)");

$conn->commit();
$conn->close();
```