# Conceito de transação Mysql PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Tem como utilizar o conceito de transação programando em PHP, pois em java tem está possibilidade.

Como fazer isto em PHP ?

> Exemplo commit, rolback...

Comment: Esta resposta vai lhe ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72474/4622

Comment: Cara, já experimentou fazer consulta no site do criador?
http://tr2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.commit.php
http://tr2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.rollback.php

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/91 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14774/91

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/para-que-serve-uma-mysql-transaction/90792#90792